# Internal Error on Virtual Directory Deployment

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, web-deployment, virtual-directory, http-status-code-500

I have an application that I need to deploy at the root of my Azure site as well as a Virtual directory - **hls**.
[image: Virtual Directory Path]

It is the same project that needs to be deployed to both the locations. The only difference is the database connection string that I change from the web.config file. Besides this, the entire MVC application is the same.

I followed the deployment from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/) with the following publish setting.
[image: Publish settings]

After deployment, I even looked into kudu and found the folder and the respective contents within.[image: Kudu screenshot]

But even so, I am unable to understand why the page returns an Internal Server Error (Error 500).

Note: The same application deployed at the root works fine.

Comment: Are the entities you used in your project existing in the database?

Comment: Yes they exist. But if this was a database connection error, it would have pointed out so, right?

Comment: It seems not point out [on my side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTgfg.png), except the connection error, it works fine.

Comment: Your error is to configure the custom error in web.config. I have already done that in mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with one of the things mentioned above, but because of a conflict in the web.config file. I didn't realize this at first, but the `web.config` file works as an inheritance. Some elements in the root application's `web.config` were also present in the child application.

In my case it was a rewrite element which converted the URLs from `http` to `https`.

Solved it by merely commenting it in the child `web.config`

Comment: Could you provide an example of the changes you made in the web.config file?

Comment: I kept the rewrite section in the root app, but removed it from the sub-app